# ¿Cómo podría agregar más clases a una función que va seleccionando elementos?

Tags: javascript

Este es mi código. Quisiera poder agregar más clases: `cuadroa`, `cuadrob`, `cuadroc`, `cuadrob`, ...

```
function figura_cruz(){
    var cruz = document.getElementsByClassName("cuadroa");
    for(var i=0; i<cruz.length; i++){
        if(cruz[i].style.visibility = "hidden"){
            cruz[i].style.display = "block";
        }else{
            cruz[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 opciones para seleccionar múltiples clases

1. O un `for` externo para repetir todo el código:

```
//Listado de clases
let clases = ['cuadroa', 'cuadrob', 'cuadroc', 'cuadrod'];

//Bucle para cada una
for (let cadaClase of clases) {
    //acá usás cadaClase que va tomando cada una de las que incluiste en el array
    var cruz = document.getElementsByClassName(cadaClase);

    // ... el resto del código
}
```

2. O usando [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para usar un único selector que seleccione a todos los elementos en una sola pasada:

```
var cruz = document.querySelectorAll('.cuadroa,.cuadrob,.cuadroc,.cuadrod');

//el resto de tu código sin modificar
for(var i=0; i<cruz.length; i++){

    // ...

}
```

- En este caso, `querySelectorAll()` utiliza un selector CSS, por lo que las clases se anteceden con un punto (`.`), y se pueden incluir varios selectores separados con comas.

Comment: a ya entiendo muchas gracias , las 2 formas me sirvieron para poder seleccionar múltiple clases , se lo agradezco